# Couldn't load pppd shared library - undefined symbol g_string_sized_new

Tags: c, shared-libraries, pppd

I've compiled shared library (pppd plugin) with no errors or warnings but when pppd tries to load this plugin, it fails with "undefined symbol g_string_sized_new" message.

Plugin source can be found here: https://raw.github.com/openshine/ModemManager/master/test/mm-test-pppd-plugin.c

To compile shared library I use the following commands:

```
gcc -fPIC -c ./mm-test-pppd-plugin.c -o mm-test-pppd-plugin.o `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
gcc -shared -o ./mm-test-pppd-plugin.so ./mm-test-pppd-plugin.o
```

As I find this g_string_sized_new should be in GLib. So as I understand it should be available systemwide?

OS: Ubuntu 13.04

Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilation is not linkage and linkage is not compilation.

On the first line, you are invoking the **compiler** so as to **compile** your C source text into object code. Here supplying the `--libs` flag to `pkg-config` is completely superfluous, pure compiler can do nothing with libraries.

However, on the second line, you are trying to **link** the resulting object files into a proper executable using the **linker,** but now you are **missing** the `pkg-config --libs` from the end of the command line - the linker needs to know the libraries to be linked against in order it to be able to resolve symbols.

[Long story short, read this.](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/Notes/compile.html)

Comment: Thanks. All I needed to do, add `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` at the end of the second line.

Comment: @UldisJansons There **do not** use `--cflags`. There's a reason (well, what I explained is **the reason**) why `--cflags` and `--libs` are two different flags for `pkg-config`.